# How do I eliminate "Can't find property" errors?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, properties

I have made an array in a program I am working on and in all functions that reference the array, no errors are returned except in one. Here's what it looks like:

```
function getAdj(id){
  getC(id);
  adj=0;
  for(i=-1;i<=1;i++){
    for(j=-1;j<=1;j++){
      if(i==0 && j==0){
        continue;
      }else if(occ[currentX+i][currentY+j]==1){
          adj++;
      }
    }
  }
  return adj;
}
```

This function returns the error (in chrome): "Can't find property" then a number (i.e the value of currentX+i) "of undefined".
Any ideas? I'm completely stumped and haven't had this problem before.

The function getC(id) btw just sets the values of currentX and currentY.
Here's how I have declared occ

```
var occ=new Array();
for(a=0;a<=gridsize;a++){
  occ[a]=new Array();
  for(c=0;c<=gridsize;c++){
    occ[a][c]=0;
  }
}
```

Comment: it means `occ` is not defined, its not declared anywhere, or you arent showing where it is declared

Comment: where are you declaring it though? in another function? in global scope?

Comment: I have tried both in a function and global. The error is the same both times

Comment: you are starting `i` and `j` off at -1, your array doesnt have a -1 as an index

Comment: You're right. In such cases where currentX==0, I get can't find property '-1' of undefined. But even when currentX+i>=0 I still get same error. e.g Can't find property '4' of undefined. The problem seems to be that it doesn't know what occ is.

Comment: in those cases you have defined `occ` in a place that your function cannot see it (ie in another function)

Comment: At the moment, occ is declared globally and is referred to by other functions that know what occ is and return no errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, but the error has gone now and is working fine  lol o.O
Anyhoo. Thanx for your input^^